# Why does Visual Studio (2008) create all these *.vsmdi files

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing

Why does Visual Studio (2008) unit testing create all these *.vsmdi files?
Can it be turned off?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer in two parts.

vsmdi files are used to store information about your tests.  So you need them when using ms' test suite in visual studio.

You should only ever have one vsmdi file in your solution.  There is a well known bug where VS keeps creating new vsmdi files (vsmdi1, vsmdi2, vsmdi3, etc) when the original is locked by source control.  There is no fix for this. You just have to be wary it's happening and delete them.